# New to Ubuntu, how do I get drivers for my USB WiFi LAN Adapter?

Tags: networking, drivers, 13.04, adapter

I reformatted an old desktop of mine to boot Ubuntu 13.04, which I will be using as a mini-server to host VPSes. It will become a headless server that I will be putting in my closet when I finish configuring it. I will simply use VNC software to connect to it when need be.

The desktop does not have a built-in WiFi adapter, so I purchased a Linksys AE2500 Dual-Band Wireless-N USB Adapter. I bought this back when the desktop ran Windows 7. I was wondering where I should start to find any drivers, or anything really that will allow me to get this adapter working on Ubuntu. Note there is no internet connection to the desktop, and I can't connect it with an Ethernet cable. I do have another laptop with internet if I need to download and transfer any files via flash drives.

I am extremely inexperienced with Linux and this project is one way I'm trying to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you don't have to install any driver manually.

In the case that your adapter (or whichever drive you use) is not working properly with open source drivers, you can use the proprietary drivers available in additional Ubuntu repositories or search for a tutorial if you need to install the drivers manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do I use the Privative Drivers built in Ubuntu, and how do I do this without any internet access? I can't connect an Ethernet cable, but my Windows 7 laptop does have access to WiFi (if that helps).